# How to make sure some JavaScript code executes only if the async/await database insertion was successful?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a back-end function which takes care of product creation. Right now, the function does its job perfectly, but it has zero error handling and I'm trying to figure how to do that eloquently.

This is the part of the code which inserts the product record into the database:

```
let product = await Product.create({
    name: name,
    description: description,
    price: price,
    manufacturer: manufacturer,
    serialNumber: serialNumber,
    image: imageUrl,
    categoryId: categoryId
})
```

And this code can only run if the product insertion in the database was successful, so I'm wondering how can I make sure it only executes if the product insertion was indeed successful?

```
Jimp.read(file.buffer)
.then(image => {
    return image
    .resize(Jimp.AUTO, 200)
    .write('public/images/products/' + imageName);
})
.catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});

models.forEach((model, i) => {
    model.addProduct(product)
});

brands.forEach((brand, i) => {
    brand.addProduct(product)
});
```

I'm curious if there are any other parts of the code that might need some error handling which I might not have forseen?

The whole function

```
module.exports.createProduct = async (req, res, next) => {
    let name = req.body.name
    let description = req.body.description
    let price = req.body.price
    let manufacturer = req.body.manufacturer
    let serialNumber = req.body.serialNumber
    let categoryId = req.body.categoryId
    let brandsIds = JSON.parse(req.body.brands)
    let modelsIds = JSON.parse(req.body.models)
    let file = req.file
    let imageName = uuidv4() + ".png"
    let imageUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + '/images/products/' + imageName

    let models = await Model.findAll({
        where: {
            id: modelsIds
        }
    });

    let brands = await Brand.findAll({
        where: {
            id: brandsIds
        }
    });

    let product = await Product.create({
        name: name,
        description: description,
        price: price,
        manufacturer: manufacturer,
        serialNumber: serialNumber,
        image: imageUrl,
        categoryId: categoryId
    })

    Jimp.read(file.buffer)
    .then(image => {
        return image
        .resize(Jimp.AUTO, 200)
        .write('public/images/products/' + imageName);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });

    models.forEach((model, i) => {
        model.addProduct(product)
    });

    brands.forEach((brand, i) => {
        brand.addProduct(product)
    });

    res.status(200).json({
        product: product
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an async await function:

```js
let product = await Product.create
```

so you can say that product variable will have a value once the product is successfully created, then you can do:

```js
if(product){
  Jimp.read(file.buffer){}
  // ...
}
```

For error handling with async/await you have to wrap your code into try and catch blocks: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

for example:

```js
try {
  let product = await Product.create
  // your code ...
}

catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, can I/should I bundle let models = await Model.findAll(), let brands = await Brand.findAll() and let product = await Product.create() in a single try/catch block, or should each one of them have their own try/catch block?

Comment: you only need a single try/catch block, put all your code inside the try block, and all the errors may happen will be handled by the catch block

Answer (score 1):

If the `Product.create` promise rejects (which I assume it will if the connection to the database fails, and probably also for something like a unique Id violation), then the code will throw.

You are not handling the exception with `try/catch` in your code, so execution of this code block will stop, and the exception will propagate up to the enclosing scope.

So it already does not run if the creation fails.